# Why doesn't my query return any rows

Tags: mysql

Structure table show [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f886e/35)

If I use query:

```
select idn
from balans as outerB WHERE idn!='' group by idn order by 
ifnull((select sum(innerB.amount) from balans as innerB 
   where innerB.idn = outerB.idn 
   and status='up'), 0) -
ifnull((select sum(innerB.amount) from balans as innerB 
   where innerB.idn = outerB.idn 
   and status='down'), 0) desc
limit 15
```

I get 2 rows.

But if I add condition `>0` :

```
select idn from Balans as outerB WHERE idn!='' AND
(
(select sum(innerB.amount) from Balans as innerB 
   where innerB.idn = outerB.idn 
   and type='up') -
(select sum(innerB.amount) from Balans as innerB 
   where innerB.idn = outerB.idn 
   and type='down')
) > 0
group by idn order by 
ifnull((select sum(innerB.amount) from Balans as innerB 
   where innerB.idn = outerB.idn 
   and type='up'), 0) -
ifnull((select sum(innerB.amount) from Balans as innerB 
   where innerB.idn = outerB.idn 
   and type='down'), 0) DESC
limit 15
```

In result I get 0 rows...

Tell me please where error? Why am I getting 0 rows?

Comment: That first query does not return 2 rows. It would return an error!?!?

Comment: @Strawberry i update all query. see now please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the `IFNULL()` in the `WHERE` condition. That is the reason you are getting 0 rows instead of 2. The Sums, returned by the subqueries, are `NULL` (that's what `SUM()` returns when there is no matching row, despite what one might think that `0` is more logical, it returns `NULL`.)

And this added condition, I'd put it in `HAVING` clause, not `WHERE` (doesn't make a difference for the results in this case but it may be more efficient):

```
select idn from Balans as outerB WHERE idn !=''
group by idn 
HAVING
ifnull((select sum(innerB.amount) from Balans as innerB 
   where innerB.idn = outerB.idn 
   and type='up'), 0) -
ifnull((select sum(innerB.amount) from Balans as innerB 
   where innerB.idn = outerB.idn 
   and type='down'), 0) > 0
order by 
ifnull((select sum(innerB.amount) from Balans as innerB 
   where innerB.idn = outerB.idn 
   and type='up'), 0) -
ifnull((select sum(innerB.amount) from Balans as innerB 
   where innerB.idn = outerB.idn 
   and type='down'), 0) DESC
limit 15 ;
```

---

I don't see a reason to write this query with correlated subqueries. You can use derived tables and simple joins (also corrected the `type` into `status`):

```
SELECT di.idn
FROM 
    ( SELECT idn
      FROM Balans
      GROUP BY idn
      HAVING idn > ''
    ) AS di
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT idn, SUM(amount) AS up
      FROM Balans
      WHERE status = 'up'
      GROUP BY idn
    ) AS bu
      ON bu.idn = di.idn
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT idn, SUM(amount) AS down
      FROM Balans
      WHERE status = 'down'
      GROUP BY idn
    ) AS bd 
      ON bd.idn = di.idn 
WHERE COALESCE(bu.up, 0) - COALESCE(bd.down, 0) > 0 ;
```

Test at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f886e/73)**

Comment: but  in result i also get 0 rows... why? P.S.: in this example in result should been 2 rows...

Comment: @AlexD he explained it in the answer... the conditions are in `WHERE` clause so the `SUM` wasn't calculated properly

Comment: @Stephan: Actually I was wrong about the HAVING-WHERE, that is not the issue. Only the missing `IFNULL()` is.

Comment: @ypercube http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f886e/43  i get 0 rows, but should be show 2 rows

Comment: In your fiddle, there are no rows with `'up'` or `'down'`. So the Sums are 0.

Comment: @ypercube i update my first query, see now please. for ex. see [**SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f886e/60)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because

```
 (select sum(innerB.amount) from Balans as innerB 
  where innerB.idn = outerB.idn 
  and type='up')
```

Isn't a number in all cases, making MySQL get confused.

As suggested, I would add **IFNULL(..)** to prevent MySQL thinking your are doing **-** on a non-number. Another option would be to do **0 + ...** just before the **(select sum...)** that should also tell MySQL that we are talking about numbers here.